# Printing PDF using PDFRenderer - shapes are not sharp

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I need to print PDF shipping label. Those labels are in PDF format. The printed shipping label has sharp text but there is problem with barcode which has little "Gear teeths" - the barcode-stripes are not smooth on the edges which is problematic for scanners.

I tried to use PDF-creator as printer and print it to the file - barcodes are sharp then (on the PC-display).

I tried also print already created file using PDF-creator (like above), then print it in PDF-Reader and barcodes are sharp in this case.

I test it on thermal Printer Zebra TLP 2844 and the printer supports only one mode 80 DPI (according to PrintService attributes)

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. Instead create an answer which you can accept after a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved, there were wrong resolution of image and the printer scaled the image itself which disturb the quality of printed image (where fonts were still sharp [I had to print both image and font on the same paper])